# Determining when an Oracle database object became invalid

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to determine **when** an object within an Oracle database became invalid?

I have tried looking at the `DBA_OBJECTS` view, but none of its date stamp columns seem to be affected when the `STATUS` changes to `'INVALID'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has to happen to make an object invalid.  Usually it's a modification to a referenced object.  Turn on database auditing on DDL and you should be able to catch changes to objects that cause other objects to become invalid.

Comment: objects can become invalid for other reasons than DDL. like rollups expiring and needed to be recalculated, changes to external dependent objects(linked servers), space constraints, etc.

Comment: @Chad, any reference to this? Oracle docs do not mention any of this, only dependencies (local or remote) and grant revocations: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general007.htm#ADMIN11557

Answer (score 2):

No.  You might be able to estimate this by looking at the timestamps of the related dependent objects (in DBA_DEPENDENCIES) - if the object was invalidated because of dropping another object then you could check the drop time of the parent in the recycle bin.  Again, this is detective work and not as straightforward as having the information presented in a view.

Answer (score 0):

**OEM Reports**
If you have OEM configured, you can look at your daily objects reports. This is a manual solution, not sure if the data in these reports is queriable or LOB data.